# Form that removes WWW. and prints result on input?

Tags: php, javascript

I need to make a form similar to the one "shorten link" sites use. It should simply remove WWW. and echo the result so I later add my code around it.

For example if the user types www.pizza.com/blablabla clicking on input should display: pizza.com/blablabla

Thanks

Comment: Is this for PHP or JavaScript? They're two different languages.

Comment: what if the user types `http://www.pizza....`?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's done. I think you have to use javascript so the result changes if the user changes what he wrote. That's why I added the javascript tag.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the `www`?  Some sites still use it.  Also, there are some sites that have different pages at both the www, and non-www versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do lots of fancy stuff with regular expressions. For example, this javascript will do what you want:

```
// Event for enter click
$("#url").keypress(
    function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#output").html(cleanURL($("#url").val()));
        }
    }
);

// Event for button click
$("#submit").click(
    function() {
        $("#output").html(cleanURL($("#url").val()));
    }
);

// Function to clean url
function cleanURL(url)
{
    if(url.match(/http:\/\//))
    {
        url = url.substring(7);
    }
    if(url.match(/^www\./))
    {
        url = url.substring(4);
    }

    return url;
}
```

Works on enter click, button click and removes both `http://` and `www`

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/ydwAb/1/

Comment: This will not work for URLs starting with `http://` albeit it was not a requisite by the OP.

Comment: Thanks, do I need jQuery to make it work? I see it works in jsfiddle but for some reason it isn't working on my page:
http://www.chusmix.com/tests/testy.html

I'm installing jQuery right now

Comment: @Liso22: It works for me chrome and FF (in your web page) I must warn you though, the enter does not work. You have to click the button, maybe that is your problem? this is easily solvable.

Comment: I installed jQuery and it works. Thanks. Can I ask you something else. Can I make it work when the user presses enter?

Comment: Yes, I was writing just about that. I probably messed up somehow but in the end it worked. And I had to install jQuery anyway. 

Is there a way to make it work with enter?
And is there a way to remove the www from the input box itsef?

Comment: Oh and I didn't realize I needed it to work with HTTP. I'll post the questions separately.

Comment: @Liso22: No, please don't do that, please edit and update this question, they are too similar to need different questions.

Comment: @Codemonkey: This is complete and correct! +1 (voted to close on second question).