# Modify what the user typed on a text box onsubmit and select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script to return what the user types on an inputbox without www.

I want the modification to work in the inputbox itself. Is this possible?

Like for example the user types: www.example.com and when he presses GO www. disappears from what he typed and then the text is highlighted (selected).

```
<input type="text" id="url" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Go!" />

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
$("#submit").click(
    function() {
        var url = $("#url").val();

        if(url.match(/^www\./))
        {
            url = url.substring(4);
        }

        $("#output").html(url);
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form that removes WWW. and prints result on input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782232/form-that-removes-www-and-prints-result-on-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `$("#url").val(url);`

http://jsfiddle.net/hk5zx/

Update:
He wants the text selected too!

```
$("#url").val(url).focus().select();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hk5zx/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click(
    function() {
        var url = $("#url"),
            val = url.val();

        if(val.match(/^www\./))
        {
            val = val.substring(4);
            url.val(val);
        }

        $("#output").html(val);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set the value through jQuery with `$("#url").attr("value", url);`.