# Remove HTTP:// and WWW from string

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Form that removes WWW. and prints result on input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782232/form-that-removes-www-and-prints-result-on-input)

I'm using this code to remove WWW. from what the user types on an input box, however it works removing the first 4 characters so it doesn't work if the user submits http://www.example.com or http://example.com.

How do I look for the strings "www." and "http://" and remove them from input?

```
<input type="text" id="url" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Go!" />

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
$("#submit").click(
    function() {
        var url = $("#url").val();

        if(url.match(/^www\./))
        {
            url = url.substring(4);
        }

        $("#output").html(url);
    }
);
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: I think the previous question should be updated since it only takes minimal modification to the accepted answer to accomplish what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you'll consider it too heavy for what you're trying to do, but a quick google search for "Javascript Uri library" brings me to [parseUri 1.2](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri).  It is basicly a regex capable of parsing the following:

source protocol authority userInfo user password host port relative path directory file query anchor